# Trying to deploy msal4jsample in tomcat server

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to enable auth for local web application using the sample provided in Azure ([msal4jsample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/ms-identity-java-webapp/)) and enable authentication using OAuth. The only available option is an implicit grant for a web app during Azure AD app registration.

Deployed it in tomcat successfully.  I am able to get an Authentication prompt from Azure AD.

However, after successful login, it is going to the error page.

I have tried to debug the application by enabling logger, unfortunately log files are not getting created.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Please share your error details.

Comment: Yeah, please share the detailed error log (response with responseid/error info) that you - so that we can help.